Как в менеджере компоновки добавить отступы нужного размера между виджетами?
Я хочу чтобы расстояние было таким же как место где крестик в местах где нарисованы палочки. 
Когда я добавляю первый виджет, он появляется в самом вверху, как видно на скриншоте, но когда добавляю второй, он появляется по середине, там где показан примерно 4-5 виджет.
Хочу чтобы они добавлялись сразу после первого, то есть не имели расстояния большого.
from PyQt6.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QFrame, QScrollArea, QSpacerItem, QSizePolicy
import sys
from style import StyleSheet


class SubWidget(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, label_text, button_text, parent_layout) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName("sub_widget")
        
        self.parent_layout = parent_layout
        self.setFixedSize(320, 45)
        self.label = QLabel(label_text)
        self.button_delete = QPushButton(button_text)
        self.button_delete.clicked.connect(self.delete_widget)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_delete, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight | Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight)

    def delete_widget(self):
        self.deleteLater()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")
        self.setObjectName("main_window")
        
        
        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        central_widget.setObjectName("central_widget")
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.scroll_area = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll_area.setObjectName("scroll_area")
        self.scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll_widget = QWidget()
        self.scroll_widget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.scroll_widget.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 10px;")
        self.widget_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.scroll_widget)
        self.widget_layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 0)
        self.widget_layout.setSpacing(15)
        self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.scroll_widget)

        create_label_btn = QPushButton("Create")
        create_label_btn.clicked.connect(self.create_label)

        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)   
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)               
        self.main_layout.addWidget(create_label_btn)
    def create_label(self) -> None:
        new_widget = SubWidget("New Label", "Delete", self.widget_layout)
        
        self.widget_layout.addWidget(new_widget, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setFixedSize(QSize(350, 500))
    window.show()
    app.exec()

Вот есть данный код, я хочу что бы расстояние между виджетами было таким же как и в самом вверху(где поставил крестик), в добавок нужно что бы виджеты создавались сразу после первого 

Danil __B, вы забыли добавить модуль style.py и объясните лучше: 1. Расстояние между добавляемыми виджетами одинаковым и по высоте как там где стоит крестик? 2.  Что значит: "...  в добавок нужно что бы виджеты создавались сразу после первого "?

Я хочу что бы расстояние было таким же как место где крестик в местах где нарисованы палочки,в когда я добавляю первый виджет,он появляется в самом вверху,как видно на скриншоте,но когда добавляю второй,он появляется по середине ,там где показан примерно 4-5 виджет,хочу что бы они добавлялись сразу после первого,то есть не имели расстояния большого ,как запустите код,думаю поймёте о чём я говорю,стили не думаю что сильно решают,можете поставить свои

Как вариант:
'''
from PyQt6.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QFrame, QScrollArea, QSpacerItem, QSizePolicy
'''
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
#? from style import StyleSheet


class SubWidget(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, label_text, button_text, parent_layout) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName("sub_widget")
        self.parent_layout = parent_layout
        self.setFixedSize(320, 45)

        self.label = QLabel(label_text)
        self.button_delete = QPushButton(button_text)
        self.button_delete.clicked.connect(self.delete_widget)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(
            self.label, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.layout.addWidget(
            self.button_delete, 
            alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight|Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight)

    def delete_widget(self):
        self.deleteLater()
        

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")
        self.setObjectName("main_window")
    
        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        central_widget.setObjectName("central_widget")
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.scroll_area = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll_area.setObjectName("scroll_area")
        self.scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll_widget = QWidget()
        self.scroll_widget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.scroll_widget.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 10px;")
        self.widget_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.scroll_widget)
        self.widget_layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 0)

# +++ ------------------------------> v <-----------------------------
        self.widget_layout.setSpacing(5)                         # 15
        self.widget_layout.insertStretch(999, stretch = 1)       # +++

        self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.scroll_widget)

        create_label_btn = QPushButton("Create")
        create_label_btn.clicked.connect(self.create_label)

        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)   
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)               
        self.main_layout.addWidget(create_label_btn)
        
    def create_label(self) -> None:
        new_widget = SubWidget(f"New Label", "Delete", self.widget_layout)
# +++
        count = self.widget_layout.count() - 1                       # +++
# -----------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvv <---------------------------------        
        self.widget_layout.insertWidget(                             # +++
            count,                                                   # +++
            new_widget,                                              # +++
            alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)                  # +++


StyleSheet = """
    #central_widget {            
        background-color: #5d7; 
        border-radius: 20px;  
    }
    #scroll_area {              
        background-color: #5f7;
        border-radius: 10px;  
    }
    #sub_widget {
        border: 2px solid #fff; 
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #abc;  
    }
    QLabel {                        
        background-color: green;    
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    QPushButton {
        background-color: gray;  
        border: none;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 10px;           
    }
"""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setFixedSize(QSize(350, 500))
    window.show()
    app.exec()



